# Generate permutation matrix from permutation vector

Tags: r, permutation

Say I have a permutation vector (row permutation)

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,7,8,5,6,9,10) # I exchanged 7 with 5 and 8 with 6.
```

Is there any function in R that can generate the corresponding permutation matrix from permutation vector? If so, please give me a example.

Comment: What did you search / try so far?

Comment: I notice there is a pMatrix class in R. But it just store a permutation matrix in sparse way and can generate permutation vector. But I don't see any function that can do from permutation vector to permutation matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this can be done by reordering the rows of the identity matrix:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,7,8,5,6,9,10)
diag(length(x))[x,]
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
#  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

This could also be done with `sparseMatrix`

```
library(Matrix)
m1 <- sparseMatrix(seq_along(v1), v1, x=1)
```

We can coerce it to `matrix` with `as.matrix`

```
as.matrix(m1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,7,8,5,6,9,10)
```

Comment: Great option for big permutation vectors!

Answer (score 0):

This what one can simply do in base R (no packages).

Let's start to set some matrix to permute.

```r
# Let us assume your nxn-matrix is
n <- 3
(M <- matrix(as.numeric(1:(n*n)), n))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

For a single permutation matrix, based on a random vector permutation (pivot), we have:

```
## To generate the permutation matrix associated to a random 1:n permutation:
vperm <- sample(1:n)
(mperm <- Reduce(\(m,i) `[[<-`(m, i, vperm[i], 1), 1:n, matrix(0, n, n)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    0
#[2,]    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    1

## To permute the columns of M:
t(mperm) %*% M
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    5    8
#[2,]    1    4    7
#[3,]    3    6    9


## And, to permute the rows of M:
M  %*%  mperm
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    4    1    7
#[2,]    5    2    8
#[3,]    6    3    9
```

Now, we generate all possible pivot vectors and the related permutation matrices

```
## To generate all possible random 1:n permutations:
vdisps <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:n), n))  # with repetitions
vperms <- Filter(\(v) length(unique(t(v))) == n, split(vdisps, 1:n^n))

## To generate the permutation matrices associated to each random permutation:
mperms <- lapply(vperms, \(permdf)
       Reduce(\(m,i) `[[<-`(m, i, permdf[[i]], 1), 1:n, matrix(0, n, n)))

## The related list of column-permutated matrices are
lapply(mperms, \(P) t(P) %*% M)
```

Of course, this is R, so we can use its subsetting features.

```
## Given 
oo <- order(vperm) #,

## we can replace t(mperm) %*% M with:
identical(t(mperm) %*% M,  M[oo, ]) # TRUE
identical(M %*% mperm,  M[, oo]) # TRUE
```

This is what is suggested to do when using the Cholesky decomposition with `chol(..., pivot = TRUE)`.

NB `as.numeric()` is important, when generating `M`, to have `identical()` to work.