# Algorithm for finding a permutation matrix of a matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, permutation

I see some similar questions:

- [Generate permutation matrix from permutation vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878215/generate-permutation-matrix-from-permutation-vector)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345166/what-is-the-name-for-a-non-square-permutation-matrix

Given elements:

```
elems =  [1,2,3,4] # dimensions 1x4
```

If I have a vector:

```
M = [4,2,3,1] # dimensions 1x4
```

I know there is some permutation matrix `p` that I can multiply `elems * p = M`, which in this case would be:

```
p = 
[ 
  0 0 0 1
  0 1 0 0 
  0 0 1 0 
  1 0 0 0 
] # dimensions 4x4

# eg: 
# elems * P = M
  1x4   4x4 = 1x4
```

Now, for my question, I am interested in what it would look like in the case when M is a non-vector, non-square matrix, like:

```
M' = [ 
  4 2 3 1 
  4 3 2 1
  1 2 3 4
] # dimensions 3x4
```

For the same

```
elems' = [
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4
] # where this is now tripled to be conformant dimensions
# dimensions 3x4
#
# meaning P is still 4x4
```

You can see `M_prime` and `elems_prime` in this case are still just permutations, but now multivariate, rather than just a single vector as originally.

I know I am not able to just do the following kind of thing, because the matrix is not square, and thus not invertible:

```
elems' * P = M'
         P = elems'^-1 * M'

# eg: 
# elems' * P = M'
  3x4   4x4  = 3x4
```

When I try, in R at least, I see:

```
> P <- ginv(elems_prime) %*% M_prime
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  0.1 0.07777778 0.08888889 0.06666667
[2,]  0.2 0.15555556 0.17777778 0.13333333
[3,]  0.3 0.23333333 0.26666667 0.20000000
[4,]  0.4 0.31111111 0.35555556 0.26666667
```

Does this give me back M'?

```
> elems_prime %*% P
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3 2.333333 2.666667    2
[2,]    3 2.333333 2.666667    2
[3,]    3 2.333333 2.666667    2

!= M' # No, does not.
```

So this is not right.

My questions are:

1. What is the right P that would correctly permute the elems' matrix
   into the M' matrix?
2. What is the name of the algorithm to find it?
   (implementation in R, Haskell, or pseudocode is great)
3. Is there a way to restrict the values of P to be integers, preferably 0 or 1?

### for R reproducibility

```
> dput(elems_prime)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), .Dim = 3:4)
> dput(M_prime)
structure(c(4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4), .Dim = 3:4)
```

Comment: I am leaning towards the idea that `P` does not exist for matrices, but not clear to me why.  I know the matrix `elems_prime` is not invertible, but the vector `elems` is also not invertible (vectors don't have inverses), yet `P` exists for `elems`.  If P exists in the matrix case, it can't be 0,1 only, must have to have negative values, possibly even non-integer values?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that column space of `M'` is of higher order than the column space of `elem'`. This implies that there does not exist a linear mapping from `elem'` to `M'` because a linear mapping cannot increase the row or column space of a matrix (useful to think about this as a transformation of basis).

It follows that the any `M'` generated by `elem' * P` can have rank of at most 1, leaving only the conventional permutation matrices as candidates for `P'`

It is an entirely different question if we look at going from `M'` back to `elem`, and this asymmetry is also noteworthy.

Comment: Are you referring to `M` and `elems`, or `M'` and `elems'`?  I am afraid I don't follow in that the column space in the latter is 4 for both terms:
```
elems'  * P   = M
 3x4    4x4    3x4
```

Comment: I am referring to `M'` and `elem'` (and have updated accordingly). "Column space" does not refer to the number of columns in a matrix, but rather to the "dimension" of the vector space spanned by the columns. The conclusion is that `P` does not exist except for the cases in which it is like the permutation matrix you gave in your example. You might want to brush up on some linear algebra (specifically vector spaces) if this answer does not yet make sense to you.

Comment: I will be the first to admit always needing more linear algebra, but I don't think your statement is correct---the column space of M' is 4, as this is the number of linearly independent columns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces  
`elem'` does have linearly dependent columns, but I'm entirely open to defining that matrix differently if it generates a permutation matrix for M'.

Comment: The dimension of the column space of `elem'` is 1 and is described by {k*(1, 1, 1) | for all real k}. When you multiply `elem'` by another matrix `M`, the columns of the product are again linear combinations of the columns in `elem'`. Thus, each column in `elem' * M` will be of the form a*(1, 1, 1)+b*(1, 1, 1)+c*(1, 1, 1)+d*(1, 1, 1)=k'*(1, 1, 1) for some k'. This shows that the columns of `elem' * M` are linearly dependent and have dimension 1 (or possibly 0). Thus, it is not possible for `elem' * M` to be equal to a full rank matrix as you desire. Yes, you need to define `elem'` differently.

Answer (score 0):

When M is not a vector, this is not possible.

Here is why.  In general if we multiple a `nxm` matrix times a `mxp` matrix we get a `nxp` matrix.  Here `elems` is a vector that is a `1x4` matrix, so `elems * P` has to be a `1x?` matrix of some sort.  By making `P` longer, you can make `M` longer, but you'd have to change `elems` to make `M` taller.

Incidentally in linear algebra it is standard to flip vectors to be columns and put the matrices on their left.  The reason for that is that the matrix represents a linear function, and that puts the matrix in the same place where the linear function goes.  So it is very nice when going from functional notation to matrix notation.  Also if you've got to write a square matrix anyways, it takes less room on the page to write a vertical vector on the right rather than a horizontal one on the left...

Comment: Thank you.  And that is true for the first case I presented, but I am looking for more than the vector in my question.  My elems_prime matrix is 3x4, M_prime is 3x4, and I am looking for the algorithm which will find a P which is 4x4.

Comment: @Mittenchops In that case go back to basics.  You've got 12 equations (one for each entry in M_prime) in 16 variables (one for each entry in your desired P).  Set up that system of linear equations and solve it with row reduction.  You should wind up with a 4 dimensional solution space.  But do be warned, the odds are that none of the possible solutions will be a permutation matrix.

Comment: There won't be any solution - the system is inconsistent. Look at the thrre equations formed by multiplying the first row of `elem'` an any arbitrary column (notice that the columns of `M'` are not linear multiples of the columns in `elem'`).